# Checkbox in MATLAB guide?

Tags: matlab, callback, matlab-guide

I have a working MATLAB GUI that consists of two tables the user fills in. When a pushdown button is clicked, it reads in the data from these tables and runs a loop over it, giving a figure output.

I wanted to edit this slightly, and added a checkbox. If the checkbox is unchecked, the code runs as normal when the button is clicked. If it is checked, a slightly different loop should be selected via if statement. This should be easy, but I must be doing something wrong as my code is producing the same results regardless of what I do. This is the code I'm trying to use; here's what happens when pushbutton clicked...

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
 function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

Fielddata = get(handles.FieldParameters, 'Data');
Envdata = get(handles.EnvParameters,'Data');         %reads in table data
Resdata = get(handles.ResParameters,'Data');

bdep = get(handles.checkbox1, 'Value'); %should read value from checkbox
```

and then later in this function;

```
  if bdep == 0; %if unchecked

    vp(n) = (B*J)./(x(n)*sdp + y(n)*scp + z(n)*sup);
    vn(n) = ((1-B)*J)./(x(n)*sdn + y(n)*scn + z(n)*sun);

  else  %if checked

   vp(n) = (J)./(x(n)*(sdp + sdn) + y(n)*(scp + scn) + z(n)*(sup + sun));
    vn(n) = (J)./(x(n)*(sdp + sdn) + y(n)*(scp + scn) + z(n)*(sup + sun));

  end
```

This simply isn't working - no matter what I do, the code seems to pay no heed to this bdep condition. I must be doing something wrong, and tried using assignin() to look at what outputs I was getting, but my second problem is that in this code, assignin doesn't seem to work for outputting to the workspace.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint after the first part of code to see what your variables look like?

Comment: http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/add-code-for-components-in-callbacks.html#f10-1001452 so you should probably change your if statement into 
if (get(handles.checkbox1,'Value') == get(handles.checkbox1,'Max'))

Comment: Or you could simply just use a switch case.